# Trying to add digits times their index

Tags: c++, hash

I'm trying to add the digits times their index in order to create a hash, but this doesn't seem to give the correct output. Can anyone tell me what's wrong here?

```
int main(){
    int i, hash=0, input;
    char temp[30];

    cin>>input;

    itoa (input, temp, 10);

    for(i=0; i<(sizeof(temp)/sizeof(*temp)); i++){
        hash+=((temp[i])*i);
    }

    cout<<hash;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not just do `string str; cin >> str`? Also, you shouldn't be using `using` really.

Comment: `itoa` is neither a standard C nor C++ function.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are hashing all the 30 bytes of temp[30] instead of hashing only the ascii representation of the integer number you are reading from stdin.

I think this is closer to what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int hash = 0;

    // Read input from stdin
    std::string input;
    std::cin >> input;

    // Make sure it contains only numbers
    if (input.find_first_not_of("0123456789") != std::string::npos) {
        std::cout << "Input doesn't contain only digits" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
        hash += (input[i] - '0') * i;
    }

    std::cout << hash << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this but it still doesn't give the right output.
Putting in 10 gives out 48, which, (1*0)+(0*1)=0 not equal to 48.

Comment: @user2027369 Ok, now I think I understand what you want. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `itoa()` returns a C-String.

*Every C-String is a buffer (just like `temp[30]`), but not every buffer is a C-String.*

The C-String must contain characters from a list of valid things (alphanumerical + some symbols + etc) and MUST finish with the "string terminator" (the character `'\0'`)

Your `temp` variable is not initialized (we could say it was born as a generic buffer, not a string yet), so after `itoa()` you will have your "number" converted to string (your buffer just became a C-String), but after the string terminator (`'\0'`) you will have any trash, once you did not initialized it!

Your buffer will be like this:

```
temp[30] = { '1', '2', '3', '\0', ?, ?, ?, ..., ? }
```

The **?**'s could be anything...

Because you loop over the whole buffer temp[30] you will be making a sum of different things all the time.

- **Solution 1:** Initialize char temp[30] = { 0 } (a little stupid, but valid)
- **Solution 2:** Loop up to the "length" of the C-String `temp`, instead of the whole buffer (this
  one makes more sense!)

This this:

```
size_t length( strlen( temp ) );

for ( size_t i( 0 ); i < length; i++ )
{
    hash += (int)i * temp[ i ];
}
```

Comment: I tried ending the loop at the length, but it doesn't give the right output. 
Input: 10
Output: 48 ((1*0)+(0*1)=0) Which is clearly wrong.

Comment: 1 = 1, 0 = 0, '1' != 1, '0' != 0 ... don't get confused the number 0 with the character '0'

Answer (score 0):

That temp[] buffer is not completely filled by itoa(), so you will be hashing garbage if you loop over i=0 to (sizeof temp)-1.  Try:

```
for (size_t i=0, n=strlen(temp); i<n; ++i)
{
    hash += (int)i*temp[i];
}
```

You'll need `<cstring>` included to define strlen().

On second thought, the no-`<cstring>` approach is probably better:

```
for (int i=0; temp[i] != 0; ++i)
{ 
    hash += i*temp[i]; 
}
```

That eliminates the (int) cast too.